# Windows XP - Run task every minute - minimized?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, console

My company seems to be hit by a virus that calls shutdown -r on all workstations. Until IT figures it out, I want to:

7. run a console program (shutdown-a) every minute
8. without it flashing a cmd.exe window on the screen.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing the timing does not have to be exact, I would just write a batch file like.

```
:Start
shutdown -a
ping -n 60 127.0.0.1
Goto Start
```

You do get one cmd prompt on-screen (which can be minimised), but it doesn't keep flashing up.

Comment: cool. I like the 'think outside the box' approach.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be this problem
http://www.f-secure.com/v-descs/msblast.shtml#details

Can you move shutdown.exe out of C:\windows\system32 temporarily?  I do that on my XP machine and then from the command line shutdown -a fails, can't find the command

Running a command minimized
http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-bat-files-invisibly-without-displaying-command-prompt/

Comment: Actually, it's probably because his company is using McAfee Anti-Virus.  The DAT file pushed today is bad. [McAfee Community Thread](http://community.mcafee.com/thread/24056?start=0&tstart=0) and [ArsTechnica Discussion](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1107765)

Comment: Yep. Big plus to @afrazier. Those were a few fun days for everybody (especially the IT guys) in the company... Thanks McAfee!

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to install things, or just have python lying around anyway (Because let's face it, why not?)

```
import time, os
while 1:
    os.system("shutdown.exe -a")
    time.sleep(60)
```

Save that in a .pyw file, and run it.
(I used this very basic idea to make a full-on scheduler a-la cron, to do all sorts of neat things. Useful!)